# How can I enable ARCamera zoom Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, virtual-reality, arcamera

I'm creating a project in augmented reality, it contains an ARCamera, how can I enable the zoom of this camera similar to the native camera of the cell phone (dragging my fingers)

[image: Project img]

I tried looking for help but I couldn't find any information

Comment: Hi Brayan! What exactly do you want to achieve by zooming? Since it's AR you cannot be talking about the actual view. Do you want to bring certain objects closer to the users face or all of them?

Comment: Hi, my idea was to expand the entire visualization, because in this application I created an ImageTarget and I would like to reach it with the zoom of the cell phone camera, thanks!

Comment: Puh, that does not sound like a typical use case for AR applications, zooming the whole visualization as the purpose of AR is to "Augment" reality which stays at constant scale as we all know;) The only thing I found regard that was this link (https://forum.unity.com/threads/ar-foundation-camera-zoom.724511/) but that only regards visualization I guess. Further interaction after zoom in is complicated I would assume. Are you sure there is no other approach to your desired goal?

Comment: This project I'm doing is a research project, so I think I can rule out this possibility of using the camera zoom, thanks for all the support, I'll close the issue!